# Haskell - Filtering a list of tuples

Tags: haskell

Consider this list of tuples:

`[(57,48),(58,49),(59,50),(65,56),(65,47),(65,57),(65,49), (41, 11)]`

I want to remove a tuple `(a, b)` if its second element `b` is equal to the first element of another tuple and all the tuples with the same `a` that come after it. For example:

The second element of `(65,57)` is 57 and the first tuple in the list `(57,48)`has 57 as its first element, so `(65,57)` should be removed and all tuples that come ***after*** it that start with 65, namely `(65,49)`. The tuples that come before it, `(65,56)` and `(65,47)`, should stay in the list.

Does anyone have an idea how to do this?

Comment: How big can that list get?

Comment: @jub0bs no bigger than 300 elements (tuples)

Comment: I would probably use [break](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:break) or [span](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:span) to split the list at the first element that satisfies the condition, and put the list back together after filtering the second part.

Comment: *I want to delete a tuple (a, b) if its second element b is equal to the first element of "another" tuple*. So perhaps you start a filtering iteration from the first element (tuple) and then carry on your iteration with the result up until there is nothing to filter. But given your filtering conditions the result will probably be different depending on the order of the list or from where you start. I think your question needs further clarification.

Comment: The problem isn't well-posed. What if there had been a tuple like `(49, 15)`? Should it be removed, or is it "safe" after `(65,49)` is removed?

Comment: @chepner there is no other tuple with `a` = 15, so it shouldn't be removed.

Comment: No, my point is that if there hadn't been a tuple that required `(65, 49)` to be removed, then `(49, 15)` *would* have been, because of `(65, 49)`. The question is: do you identify which tuples should be removed *before* you actually remove any, or is it a strict left-to-right sweep?

Comment: @chepner No, I "order" the tuples before calling the function, it is a strict left-to-right sweep.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For efficiency (single pass), you should create two sets, one for elements you've seen as the first elements of tuples, the other for elements you've seen both as first and second elements (ie. delete if matches first element).

Something like,

```
{-# LANGUAGE PackageImports #-}

import "lens" Control.Lens (contains, (.~), (^.), (&))
import "yjtools" Data.Function.Tools (applyUnless, applyWhen)
import qualified "containers" Data.IntSet as Set

filterTuples :: Foldable t => t (Int, Int) -> [(Int, Int)]
filterTuples = flip (foldr go $ const []) (Set.empty, Set.empty)
  where
    go p@(x,y) go' (fsts, deletes) =
      let seenFst = fsts ^. contains y
          shouldDelete = seenFst || deletes ^. contains x
          fsts' = fsts & contains x .~ True
          deletes' = deletes & applyWhen seenFst (contains y .~ True)
      in  applyUnless shouldDelete (p:) $ go' (fsts', deletes')
```

EDITs: for correctness, clarity, spine-laziness

Comment: What does the `.:` do in line one? It seems to cause a parse error when trying to compile the function

Comment: @iMazing I wasn't at a computer, it wasn't quite right, I've corrected it now and it now longer uses that function but it should have been from composition package, `(.:) f g x y = f $ g x y`

Answer (score 1):

You could start by creating a distinct set of all the first elements, e.g.:

```
Prelude Data.List> firsts = nub $ fst <$>
                              [(57,48),(58,49),(59,50),(65,56),(65,47),
                               (65,57),(65,49), (41, 11)]
Prelude Data.List> firsts
[57,58,59,65,41]
```

You could use `break` or `span` as Robin Zigmond suggests. You'll need a predicate for that. You could use `elem`, like this:

```
Prelude Data.List> elem 48 firsts
False
Prelude Data.List> elem 49 firsts
False
...
Prelude Data.List> elem 57 firsts
True
```

If you're concerned that `elem` is too inefficient, you could experiment with creating a [Set](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers/docs/Data-Set.html) and use the `member` function instead.

Comment: How can I use this as a predicate if my list strictly has tuples and no single elements?

Comment: @iMazing I think you'll need to write a function with a type like `(Int, Int) -> Bool`, and then use `elem` in that function, as outlined above.

Comment: Aaaaaaa `nub` AaaAaAaaaa `ordNub` AAAAA

Answer (score 0):

I'm an absolute beginner in haskell, so there probably is a much more elegant/efficient solution for this. But anyways I wanted to share the solution I came up with:

```
filterTuples :: [(Int, Int)] -> [(Int,Int)]
filterTuples [] = []
filterTuples (x:xs) = x:filterTuples(concat ((fst temp) : [filter (\z -> fst z /= del) (snd temp)]))
    where del = fst (head (snd temp))
          temp = break (\y -> (snd y == fst x)) xs
```

(Glad for feedback on how to improve this)

Comment: Can you compile this on your machine? It throws a "Variable not in scope: test :: [(Int, Int)] -> [(Int, Int)]" error.

Comment: @iMazing: likely it should be `filterTuples`, not `test`.

Comment: Ops, forgot to change the function name. It should be filterTuples instead of test

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps try using `mapAccumL` starting with the initial list as the accumulator. Then maintain a `Predicate` as a parameter too which acts as a decider for what has been seen, and this will determine if you can output or not at each step in the traversal.

Answer (score 0):

`f` consumes a list of pairs: `xs`; it produces a new list of pairs: `ys`. `ys` contains every pair: `(a, b)` in `xs`, except the pair whose second element `b`: previously occurred as first elements: `a`. When such a pair: `(a, b)` is encountered, subsequent pairs that have `a` as their first elements are excluded from `ys`.

```
f xs = go xs [] []
  where
    go [] ys zs        = ys
    go (x@(a,b):xs) ys zs 
      |  b `elem` as  = go xs ys (a:zs)
      |  a `elem` zs  = go xs ys zs
      | otherwise     = [x] ++ go xs ys zs
    as = (nub . fst . unzip) xs
```

Comment: Doesn't this match second elements against first elements that occurred anywhere rather than just previously?